# ajax is not defined jquery when sending request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting this exception

> $.ajax is not a function

In this bellow code! I have made enough research I am not getting the proper solution. I have not used slim version of CDN. I am using bootstrap in this HTML file, does it have anything to do with?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Great India</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
          </div>
        </form>
        <button id="signup" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="rest.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("#signup").click(function()
    {
      var json='{"id":"SomeId","title":"SomeTitle"}';
      var obj=JSON.parse(json);

          $.ajax({
            url:"http://127.0.0.1:8080/signup",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: obj,
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            timeout: 5000,
            complete: function() {
              //called when complete
              console.log('process complete');
            },

            success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              console.log('process sucess');
           },

            error: function() {
              console.log('process error');
            },
          });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to send a request to a node js server.

Comment: Why do you have two links to JQuery and Bootstrap?

Comment: *I have not used slim version of CDN !I* **Yes you are! It's right there near the end of the HTML**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have not used slim version of CDN !

You have two identical `script` links to JQuery min (one right after the other) **and one to JQuery slim**:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The JQuery slim script reference comes after the JQuery min links and so it overwrites the `$` reference and JQuery slim excludes AJAX functionality.

FYI: You also have two identical links to Bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you ! Just found it ! After 9 min I will select your answer as correct !